Hive Table Issues with MSCK REPAIR and Alter Table Operations
I have a table test in Hive using ParquetHiveSerDe. The dataset is large with 10+ columns, but here’s a sample version:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TEST (
  name string,
  age int,
  address string
) 
PARTITIONED BY (
  date string
)
LOCATION '/data'


The table has two partitions: date=2023 (old data) and date=2024 (new data with additional columns).
After creating the table, running SHOW PARTITIONS test returns no results, so I run MSCK REPAIR TABLE test to update the metastore. This works, and I can query the data correctly.

I then add a new column:
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMNS (city string); 
When I query SELECT * FROM test WHERE date=2024, I get:
| Name | Age | Address | City |
|------|-----|---------|------|
| abc  |  22 | address1 | NULL |
| def  |  23 | address2 | NULL |

I expect to see NULL for date=2023, but no data appears for date=2024.
Running MSCK REPAIR TABLE test doesn't help. However, if I drop and add the partition, I see the correct data.
Why do I need to drop and add the partition again after refreshing the Hive metastore? Also, how does MSCK REPAIR TABLE test differ from ALTER TABLE test DROP PARTITION (date='2024') followed by ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (date='2024'), and is one method preferred over the other?
